# Duplication top of stack item in IL without helper variable

Tags: .net, stack, cil, il

Is it possible to copy top stack item and push it back?
I only know about solution with using of helper local variable like this:

```cs
stloc.n
ldloc.n
ldloc.n
```

Are IL instructions for copying stack items exist? Is it possible to avoid using of helper local variable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you look at [`OpCodes.Dup`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reflection.emit.opcodes.dup.aspx), it duplicates the top stack item?

Comment: It's really exists.. Sorry for my inattention.

Comment: It does and is very useful :) If I answered your question, can you mark it as such?